# Validate against an array

Tags: powershell, while-loop

I'm trying to setup a validation check against an array. I have the following

```
$ValidDomain = "*.com","*.co.uk"
$ForwardDomain = Read-Host "What domain do you want to forward to? e.g. contoso.com"
#while (!($ForwardDomain -contains $ValidDomain)) {
while (!($ValidDomain.Contains($ForwardDomain))) {
    Write-Warning "$ForwardDomain isn't a valid domain name format. Please try again."
    $ForwardDomain = Read-Host "What domain do you want to forward to? e.g. contoso.com"
}
```

The commented `while` line is just an alternative way I've been testing this.

If I enter, when prompted by `Read-Host`, "fjdkjfl.com" this displays the warning message rather than saying it's valid and keeps looping.

I have tried using `-match` instead of `-contains` but get the message:

> parsing "*com *co.uk" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.

Have I got this completely wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Contains()` and `-contains` don't work the way you expect. Use a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference) instead:

```
$ValidDomain = '\.(com|co\.uk)$'
$ForwardDomain = Read-Host ...
while ($ForwardDomain -notmatch $ValidDomain) {
    ...
}
```

You can construct `$ValidDomain` from a list of strings like this:

```
$domains = 'com', 'co.uk'
$ValidDomains = '\.({0})$' -f (($domains | ForEach-Object {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|')
```

Regular expression breakdown:

- `.`: The dot is a special character that matches any character except newlines. To match a literal dot you need the escape sequence `\.`.
- `(...)`: Parentheses define a (capturing) group or subexpression.
- `|`: The pipe defines an alternation (basically an "OR"). Alternations are typically put in grouping constructs to distinguish the alternation from the rest of the expression.
- `$`: The dollar sign is a special character that matches the end of a string.

The `{0}` in the format string for the `-f` operator is not part of the regular expression, but a placeholder that defines where (and optionally how) the second argument of the operator is inserted into the format string.

Comment: Thanks very much. Works like a treat. I'm a little confused with the syntax for the $ValidDomain variable. More so the "\" & "$" characters and placement of "(" & ")". Thanks for the construct addition, very useful.

Comment: Even better thanks. Much clearer. The only thing that bamboozles me now is that I'd expect '(\.com|co\.uk)$' but why's the opener bracket located where it is?

Comment: Actually I see it. It's basically saying a literal dot for everything before each item listed in the Parentheses. Gotcha thanks.